# Text and Widgets in a single line [shiny]

Tags: css, r, shiny, widget

The following code keeps *text* and *widgets* in a single line, however, like to know the possibility of better ways, if any. Also, as you see, widgets are not properly aligned; it was looking good on RStudio viewer though.
Here is the image 
[image]

Here is reproducible code

```
server <- function(input, output) {
}
ui <- fluidPage(
      tabPanel("Test",
               div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:moddle; width: 175px;",
                   p("Choose a threshold that is ")),
               div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:middle; width: 100px;",
                   textInput("var1","","2")),
               div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:middle; width: 100px;",
                   selectInput("var2","",c("inches","cm")))
      ))
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: why don't you try a google MDL? it's easier and you don't need to type that kind of js anymore.

Comment: You have a misspelling - 'vertical-align:moddle;'

Comment: @ovokuro Agree. Correct spelling, i.e., "middle" did not solve the problem, i.e., widgets slightly misaligned on chrome browser.

Comment: @Obink Is MDL stands for Material Design Lite?

Comment: @SatishR ye it is. sorry late reply. A bit busy